# Fix Safari 6 Address Bar Selection Behavior

Tags: safari, text-input

This is probably just something I have to live with, but with Safari 6 Apple made the address bar different from every other text field on the OS, in that a single click (at least when it's displaying a URL) selects the entire contents of the text field rather than placing the insertion point.

It's probably a long shot, but is there a `defaults write` command or similar that fixes this?

Answer (score 1):

This is built-in to Safari 6. To the best of my knowledge, there is (currently) no flag to control this with.